# Flutter Firebase Cloud Messaging: for what is the `onBackgroundMessage` used for?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification

I setup my flutter app with push notifications but I have no idea what is the following code used for:

```
  _initiateFcm() async {
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  }

  Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    print('A bg message just showed up: ${message.messageId}');
  }
```

I don't find an example where it is used for anything else than initializing the firebase app... what happens already in my `main()` method. What is the purpose of this? When should it be used for what?

I have these functions where I actually handle the push notifications I get:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {});
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {});
```

But I don't use the `onBackgroundMessage` for anything...

The documentation says:

```
  /// Set a message handler function which is called when the app is in the
  /// background or terminated.
  ///
  /// This provided handler must be a top-level function and cannot be
  /// anonymous otherwise an [ArgumentError] will be thrown.
```

But nobody is using this method for anything anywhere I check...

Answer (score 1):

```
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage()
```

This function is called when your notifications are received while the application is not running (application is in background).

So, if there are things you want to do when background notification is received, you can use this function.

You can use the function to perform logic such as HTTP requests, IO operations (updating local storage), communicate with other plugins when you receive a notification while the app is not running.

NB: It is not possible to update application state or execute any UI impacting logic from this function (Since the handler runs in its own isolate outside your applications context).

More [info](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/)